# navigation using bloc 8 and auto_route 3.2.0

Tags: flutter, navigation, bloc

I'm trying to show screens using [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route), based on state kept using bloc. I have two objectives:

1. navigate when button is clicked (e.g. login)
2. if at any point, the state changes, again navigate to the correct screen (e.g. session expiry)

for usecase 1 I have a button:

```
               child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  final sessionBloc = BlocProvider.of<SessionBloc>(context);
                  sessionBloc.add(SignInEvent());
                },
                child: const Text('Login'),
              ),
```

this delegates to my session bloc that has a handler that is defined as:

```
    emit(
      SignedIn(
        const User(
            displayName: 'displayName',
            phoneNumber: 'phoneNumber',
            idNumber: 'idNumber',
            photoUrl: 'photoUrl'),
      ),
    );
```

and I'm trying to use an authguard defined as:

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {

  AuthGuard({required Stream<SessionState> sessionBloc}) {
    sessionBloc.listen((state) {
      print('['+state.toString()+']');
      _authenticated = state is SignedIn;
    });
  }

  bool _authenticated = true;

  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) {
    if (!_authenticated) {
      router.push(
        LoginRouter(),
      );
    }
    resolver.next(true);
  }
}
```

I can see the print statement everytime I press the button, so that works fine (no surprise).

The problem is that I don't get any navigation to another screeen when pressing the button. I can only assume this is because although I'm updating the state and the authguard is aware of the new state, it does nothing till we actually try navigating i.e. onNavigate is called.

**So how do I do that, how/where do I trigger navigation?**

Comment: As a workaround;  ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                BlocProvider.of<SessionBloc>(context).add(SignoutEvent());
                ///turns out add is async in nature hence the await below
                ///before i can navigate manually
                await BlocProvider.of<SessionBloc>(context).stream.first;
                context.navigateTo(HomeRoute());
              },
              child: Text('Sign Out'),
            ),

Answer (score 0):

I would use either BlocConsumer or BlocListner and inside the listen method do the navigation to the desired screen. And make sure there is a route guard on the route you want to navigate to after authentication.

```
        BlocListener<SessionBloc, SessionState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if(state is SignedIn){
          //TODO: route to the page you want to go to
          
        }
      },
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          final sessionBloc = BlocProvider.of<SessionBloc>(context);
          sessionBloc.add(SignInEvent());
        },
        child: const Text('Login'),
      ),
    );
```